# How to use two separetor in scanner.nextDouble() ? java

Tags: java, parsing, input

I want to read double numbers of both format(123,123 and 123.123).

```
Scaner scaner = new Scaner(new File("in"));
//How to set the scanner up to read double of two formats?
double d = scaner.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way to read both formats using Scanner, but only to write your own reading method

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your locale correctly. e.g.

```
scan.useLocale(Locale.UK);
```

You don't want `123,456.0` to be read as `123.456` incorrectly.

If you want to use Scanner, you can do this in combination

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(scanner.next().replace(',', '.'));
```

Comment: Universe should decide to use one of `.` or `,`.. Once decided, the other should be illegal :)